# API Facebook de compartilhamento

Tags: javascript, mobile, facebook, facebook-sdk, api

Tenho um sistema responsivo, onde criei um webview para android e ios com esse sistema para usa-lo como aplicativo. Até aí ok. Então, implementei um botão de compartilhamento do Facebook conforme documentação do Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web). Fiz a implementação por código Javascript.

Implementei pra web porque o app esta todo na web. No app esta somente o webview.

Ele até funciona, tanto no desktop, quanto no aplicativo. Porém, depois que eu faço o compartilhamento o app fica com a tela toda branca, ele não volta para a url do meu site.

Acredito que isso acontece porque quando faço o compartilhamento no desktop, abre um pop-up do facebook pra eu fazer o compartilhamento, e depois que faço o compartilhamento esse pop-up fecha sozinho.

Então acho que essa tela branca no aplicativo se deve a esse pop-up ter fechado.

Acho que resolveria se eu passar pra API do Facebook uma url de redirecionamento após o compartilhamento, assim, eu compartilho e depois sou redirecionado pra alguma url.

Mas pesquisando sobre isso não achei nada na documentação do Facebook nem na internet.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com alguma solução?

Desde já agradeço!

## ================================

Segue código do botão para compartilhamento no Facebook:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK -->
<div align="center" class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
    <div align="center" class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.site.com<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="false">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /FACEBOOK -->
```

E o SDK Javascript do Facebook:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId            : 'APP_ID',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.12'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
});
```

Comment: Não estou usando esse parâmetro não. Não vi ele em nenhum lugar da doc. Assim que chegar em casa eu posto o código. Obrigado!

Comment: @Guilherme, coloquei os códigos que estou usando para fazer o compartilhamento. Dei mais uma olhada lá na doc do Facebook e não achei nada relacionado a redirect_uri

Comment: Acompanhei o processo pelo debugger mas ele não chamou nenhum arquivo que indique close popup :/
O estranho é que na doc diz que se passar um parametro chamado data-mobile-iframe como true, em dispositivos móveis ele usa um iframe ao invés de abrir o pop up, mas mesmo passando esse parametro como true ele fica da mesma forma.
Mas quando eu abro o site pelo navegador do smartphone funciona. Ele abre o pop up, eu digito algo ou deixo em branco e clico em confirmar, ai ele abre uma nova aba só perguntando se confirma o compartilhamento.

Acho que essa nova aba que faz nao funcionar no webview